# Spring Framework: Filter broadcast messages before sending them to the clients

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm working on a Java Spring Boot Application which broadcasts data to all subscribed clients. All the data always have a timestamp field that shows the time the data was created on. All clients should now be able to filter by start and end times.
The idea is that every client subscribes to different topics and first gets all the data within the selected timeframe by a GET request, after that they only get updates when new data is being added within their selected timeframe. So I send a GET request and get back all the data via WebSocket that matches the specified timeframe.

This works all so far, except that the new data is only being broadcasted to clients that match the selected timeframe.

Inside my REST controller, I use the `SimpMessagingTemplate` to broadcast the data to the respective topics. Now I need some kind of interceptor which allows me to filter the data before being broadcasted to the clients. Is there some way to solve this problem in the backend or do I have to filter the data on the client-side? I just think that it is really inefficient to broadcast all data to all clients and the client then just discards all data that it doesn't need.

This is my websocket configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    public static final String COMMANDS_QUEUE = "/commands";
    public static final String FILES_QUEUE = "/files";
    public static final String DATA_QUEUE = "/data";

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker(
                WebSocketConfig.COMMANDS_QUEUE,
                WebSocketConfig.FILES_QUEUE,
                WebSocketConfig.DATA_QUEUE);
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/cdh/websocket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .addInterceptors(new HttpHandshakeInterceptor())
                .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Upon connecting, the client retrieves all commands within the selected timeframe which is done by building a predicate and setting the start and end time:

```
@GetMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(OK)
public void getCommands(CommandProperties commandProperties) {
    List<Command> commands = commandService.getCommands(commandProperties.buildPredicate(),
            new PageRequest(commandProperties.getPageIndex(), commandProperties.getPageSize()));
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(WebSocketConfig.COMMANDS_QUEUE,
            commands.stream().map(commandMapper::toMessage).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Whenever I create a new command the new command is broadcasted to all clients:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(CREATED)
public CommandMessage createCommand(@Valid @RequestBody CommandMessage commandMessage) {
    Command command = commandService.createCommand(commandMapper.toResource(commandMessage));
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(WebSocketConfig.COMMANDS_QUEUE, commandMapper.toMessage(command));
    return commandMapper.toMessage(command);
}
```

And now the last missing piece is how to filter the data being broadcasted by start and end time?

Thanks in advance for your support :)

Comment: Please provide the relevant parts of your code.